# How to intercept incoming/outcoming sms and send it to another device or email

Tags: objective-c, sms

I'd like to realize an application allowing to catch incoming and outcoming sms each time an sms is recived or sent and send it to another mobile or to an email address. So should I touch the mobile substrate (if yes HOW?? I didn't found anything on how to developp this kind of application)? how to catch the send/recive sms event?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in a non jail broken iOS device. Just think of the implications...

On a broken device you will need to monitor `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db` for changes and then query it to find the messages.

Comment: I plan to use it only for me and I have a jailbroken device